# How to find duplicate element and remove them in the list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have two lists as follows:

```
name =[A,    B  ,  C  , D   , E ,  F  ]
cls=[1,    2  ,  3  , 2   , 4 ,  1  ]
score=[0.1, 0.2 , 0.5 , 0.3 , 1 , 0.8 ]
```

It means A belongs to class 1 and its score 0.1, B belongs to class 2 and its score is 0.2, and so on.

I am looking for a method to find object has the same class, and remove the object if its score is smaller than another object in the class (`cls`). So, My expected result is

```
name =[C  , D   , E ,  F  ]
cls  =[3  , 2   , 4 ,  1  ]
score=[0.5 ,0.3 , 1 , 0.8 ]
```

The `name`, `cls` and `score` are list type. How can I implement it in python? Thanks

This is what I did

```
name_clean=[]
cls_clean=[]
score_clean=[]
for i in range(len(cls)-1):
    cls_i=cls[i]
    max_index = -1
    for j in range(i+1,len(cls)):
        cls_j = cls[j]
        if (cls_i==cls_j):
            if (score[i]<=score[j]):
                max_index=j
            else:
                max_index=i
    if (max_index>=0):
        name_clean.append(name[max_index])
        cls_clean.append(cls[max_index])
        score_clean.append(score[max_index])
    else:
        name_clean.append(name[i])
        cls_clean.append(cls[i])
        score_clean.append(score[i])
```

Comment: Hi, this is not code completion service. Read how to make questions: [describe the problem and **what has been done so far to solve it**.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is asking to others to do their own work.

Comment: I tried it by using two for loops but it not the success. Hence, I ask in here. Why it is close?

Comment: Please show your efforts... And the first step would be to use the right data structure.

Comment: Don't be afraid, 5 votes are needed to close the question. Sure someone desperate to get 1k will do your work to get some up-votes.

Comment: Note that `class` is not a valid identifier in Python (it's a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html)).

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question that shows what I did

Comment: Do you want to keep all highest values for each class or just one. I mean in case you have multiple same scores for the same class.

Comment: Right. That is what I expect. If the same score and same class. Just choose the first one

Comment: Q : "do you want A or B"  - A : "yes"

Comment: Sorry, I did not read whole question

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Sounds like a legit interpretation of `or`: "Yes, I do want A or B.". :-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe --->[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you cannot use `class` as a variable name because it's a reserved keyword in Python.

Instead of using 3 lists I would consider using one list containing [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s or a Table, e.g. [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).

However since you have it as 3 lists I would do it like this:

Get the highest score for each class and store it in a dictionary

```
highest_scores = {}
for c, s in zip(cls, score):
    current_max = highest_scores.get(c, None)
    if current_max is None or current_max < s:  # not present or smaller
        highest_scores[c] = s
```

Then iterate over the lists again and only keep those that have a score that is equal to the stored score for that class:

```
new_name = []
new_cls = []
new_score = []
for n, c, s in zip(name, cls, score):
    if s == highest_scores[c]:
        new_name.append(n)
        new_cls.append(c)
        new_score.append(s)
```

Which gives:

```
>>> new_name
['C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
>>> new_cls
[3, 2, 4, 1]
>>> new_score
[0.5, 0.3, 1, 0.8]
```

Note that this would keep all "highest scores" for each class, so if you have the same class and the same score this would keep both. To fix that you could remove the key from the dictionary as soon as you found the first.

```
for n, c, s in zip(name, cls, score):
    if c in highest_scores and s == highest_scores[c]:
        new_name.append(n)
        new_cls.append(c)
        new_score.append(s)
        del highest_scores[c]
```

Comment: Perfect!. I got it. Thanks so much

Comment: "Instead of using 3 lists I would consider using one list containing namedtuples or a Table" => or just plain tuples...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yeah, so would lists/dicts/custom classes. I wanted to show the easiest alternatives where you don't lose the name of the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Using the right data structure helps a lot. In your case, you want to regroup your data by `class`:

```
names = ["A",  "B", "C", "D", "E",  "F"]
classes = [1,  2  ,  3  , 2   , 4 ,  1]
scores = [0.1, 0.2 , 0.5 , 0.3 , 1 , 0.8]

byclasses = defaultdict(list)
for name, class_, score in zip(names, classes, scores):
    byclasses[class_].append((score, name))

print byclasses
```

At this stage what you get is:

```
{1: [(0.1, 'A'), (0.8, 'F')], 
 2: [(0.2, 'B'), (0.3, 'D')], 
 3: [(0.5, 'C')], 
 4: [(1, 'E')]
}
```

Now you just have to sort each of the lists (they will be sorted on score ascending) and keep the last item of each list (which will be the one with the highest score)

```
cleaned = [((k,) + sorted(v)[-1]) for k, v in byclasses.items()]
print cleaned
```

which gives you a list of (class, score, name) tuples:

```
[(1, 0.8, 'F'), (2, 0.3, 'D'), (3, 0.5, 'C'), (4, 1, 'E')]
```

and - if you insist on having three lists instead of a list of tuple  - unzip the result to three new lists:

```
cnames, cclasses, cscores = (list(c) for c in zip(*cleaned))
print cnames, cclasses, cscores
```

and here we are:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] [0.8, 0.3, 0.5, 1] ['F', 'D', 'C', 'E']
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution splits the problem into 2 distinct steps,

1. Find the maximum score for each class of item and store it a map
2. Create new lists which contain only items corresponding to maximum score

Note the use of set() to find distinct classes,

```
name = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
cls = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1]
score = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 1, 0.8]

# find largest score for each class
max_class_scores = {} # key is class, value is max score
for c in set(cls):
    # contains max score for a class
    max_class_scores[c] = max(s for (i,s) in enumerate(score) if cls[i]==c)

new_name = []
new_cls = []
new_score =[]
for n,c,s in zip(name,cls,score):
    max_score = max_class_scores[c]
    if s == max_score :  # only process where the current record is max for the class
        new_name.append(n)
        new_cls.append(c)
        new_score.append(s)

print(new_name,new_cls,new_score)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

name=['A','B','C','D','E','F']
cls=[1,2,3,2,4,1]
score=[0.1,0.2,0.5,0.3,1,0.8]

f=itemgetter(1)
g=itemgetter(2)
groups=groupby(sorted(zip(name,cls,score), key=f), key=f)

name, cls, score = zip(*map(lambda x: max(x, key=g), ((item for item in data) for (key, data) in groups)))
```